# How to apply filters to a kendo grid datasource on startup

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datasource

I have a application that has a kendo grid.

I can filter the grid using several dropdownlists that are outside the grid.

When I click on search, I add filters to the datasource filter list. For example,

```
var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
            var dataSourceFilterQuery = new Array();

    if ($("#something").data("kendoDropDownList").value() !== null) {
                    dataSourceFilterQuery.push({ field: "something", operator: "IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo", value: ($("#something").data("kendoDropDownList").value()) });
            }

            dataSource.filter(dataSourceFilterQuery);
```

Then I get the results I want. It works.
I then have the possibility of saving the values of all the dropdownlists as one filter in localStorage.

```
 const filtersObject = {
                Something: whatever.value(),
                ...
            };

            this.storage.setItem("Filter", JSON.stringify(filtersObject));
```

When I restart the application, the dropdownlists are populated with whatever is in localStorage

```
const filter =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Filter"));

                $("#something").data("kendoDropDownList").value(filters.whatever || "");                
            }
```

The thing is, I wanted to add these filters, if they exist on localStorage, to the datasource when the application starts so that the user can see the results of the filter he saved when the applications starts and not have to click on search again.

So, what I want is to do apply this

```
var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
            var dataSourceFilterQuery = new Array();

    if ($("#something").data("kendoDropDownList").value() !== null) {
                    dataSourceFilterQuery.push({ field: "something", operator: "IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo", value: ($("#something").data("kendoDropDownList").value()) });
            }

            dataSource.filter(dataSourceFilterQuery);
```

before the grid is displayed.

Is this possible?

Tks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the Grid with

```
autoBind: false
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-autoBind

and when the page loads, call your filter setup, then trigger the grid load manually (via dataSource.read())